# Should operator< for std::string be affected by current locale?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, libstdc++

I am a bit surprised about this fact

```
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    printf("Floating point format: %.7g\n",1.4);
    std::string a("Hello, World/#");
    std::string b("Hello, World 2");

    assert(a>b); 

    assert(setlocale(LC_ALL,"sv_SE.UTF-8")!=NULL);
    printf("New floating point format: %.7g\n",1.4);

    assert(b<a);
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b435636e4ff7161

This program exits normally. Conclusion, the locale affects the comparison between a and b. Is that correct? This means that the sorting invariant is broken by change of the current locale when using std::string as key in std::set et al, without a custom comparison function.

Comment: Uhh, you have the same logical assertion in both places, just using different operators.

Comment: [`basic_string`'s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) `operator<` uses [`char_traits::compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) by default, which provides [a lexicographical ordering based on `char_traits::eq` and `char_traits::lt`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/compare). *Those* [compare based on the built-in operators for `unsigned char`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/cmp). IOW, it's not locale-dependent.

Comment: if you're going to set locale you should set the [c++ locale](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/global) which automatically sets the C locale too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should operator< for std::string be affected by current locale?

No. The operators use `std::string::compare` internally. That in turn uses `std::string::traits_type` for comparisons. `std::string::traits_type` is `std::char_traits<char>` which is locale independant.

> Conclusion, the locale affects the comparison between a and b.

No such conclusion can be made, since the ordering has remained the same between the assertions.

Answer (score 1):

Your conclusion is wrong: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/38971b91c881da2c

`a>b` is equivalent to `b<a`, you sure meant to use `a<b` or `b>a` for the second `assert`.